# Splitting out very large enums in java/groovy

Tags: java, design-patterns, groovy, enums, data-modeling

I'm currently designing a model in Groovy.
So, I have a static amount of values that I need to map on a model.

So for example:

```
class Model () {
    StaticValues values
}
```

Initially, I was thinking of implementing this unto an enum.

```
enum StaticValues {
    VALUE!, VALUE2, ...
}
```

The problem is, it will eventually become really big, it might contain hundreds of elements. Since subclassing enums are not possible, are there alternative approaches to this problem?

The StaticValues are plain hardcoded constants. These values could even be represented as plain string.

However, these values are going to be used as keys for querying this model.  So it is important for it to contain only valid values. That is why I intend to make the values field "typed" rather than string.

Comment: It's hard to suggest an alternative without knowing more about the problem you're trying to solve.  It may be that an enum with hundreds of constants is appropriate.  Or it may be the case that an enum is the wrong approach altogether.

Comment: What specific problem are you facing with an enum that contains hundreds of members? Also, you mention subclassing enums. Are you looking for a solution that can handle hierarchy?

Comment: @VGR I need to make sure that only valid values would be assigned on the 'values' field. So, Im trying to make it type-safe.

Comment: @AndyThomas I'm not entirely sure if having an enum with hundereds of members is bad, but I'm not sure its the best approach for this problem. I was considering polymoprhism just to split those constants up at the same time retain type safety on the 'values' field.

Comment: please give more info. you say the number of values is static, but could *potentially* be hundreds. so you generate the enum? where do the values come from? who defines them? who , how or what will use the values? generated code too? a user. code you write, or will it be part of an API? are you wrapping an API from an other language? please edit your question, adding all the info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement an interface with `enum` and you can have multiple `enum` which implement this interface or a sub class.

BTW a few hundred enum shouldn't be a problem.